# Subclassing UIView/UIViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uibutton

I need a lot of custom buttons in my app. At the moment I'm using storyboard to define these buttons on every controller that I need. However, I feel that since I need them throughout my app, I'm better off putting in a different view controller/view that subclasses `UIView` or `UIViewController` so if I need to make any changes I will just have to do them once as opposed to in different view controllers. What would be the best way to do this? Also can you tell me how can I create buttons programatically? This is what I'm doing at the moment, and I'm getting a completely blank screen.

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated 
{ 
    UIButton *testButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [testButton setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 390, 100, 40)];
    [testButton setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin];
    [setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"test_button"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"test_button"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];  
    [setEnabled:YES];
    [self.view addSubview:testButton];
 }
```

Comment: your setImage and setEnabled lines, are those for the button or the view controller? also, are you leaving out [super viewDidAppear:animated]; on purpose?

Comment: That code wouldn't even compile. You need to have testButton in front of setImage and setEnabled, then it should work (assuming that you actually create those images -- if not, the button will be invisible).

Comment: Np, the superview DidAppear:animated is there, I just forgot to paste it. The setImage and setEnabled are for the button. What do you mean by ahve testButton in front setImage and setEnabled? Not sure what you're referring to when you say image creation, I have the images as supporting files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is a chance that your button is way off the visible rect. for adding the button programmatically, you are doing it mostly right. also, images should have the file extension. since you are adding a customButton, if there are no images, then you wont see any button. Try adding a title to your button, which would show up even if there is no image added.

try the code below.

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated { 
    [super viewDidAppear:animated]; //you must have a good reason to not add this line.
    UIButton *testButton=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [testButton setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 20, 100, 40)];
    [testButton setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin];
    [testButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"test_button.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [testButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"test_button.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted]; 
    [testButton setEnabled:YES];
    [self.view addSubview:testButton];
 }
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked. Now that I have this, what am I supposed to do in mother controller files in order to inherit this/exhibit this behavior in some way in that  I want this button across multiple controllers.

Comment: I guess you are wanting to have multiple instances of the same viewController or instances of viewControllers that inherit from this controller. in either case, in each of the derived/sub/child class' viewDidAppear (if you are implementing it), just call the [super viewDidAppear:animated]; the testButton for that class will be added.

Comment: Hmm, but how do I create a relationship between this controller and others. like when i write superviewDidappear how will it know that I'm referring to this particular controller?

Comment: So, Essentially what I have now is a view controller with three buttons at the bottom of the screen. I need these buttons to be across multiple screens on my app. So what do I do in my already existing other controllers (like mapview controllers, table view controllers etc.) so they can inherit this view controller with the buttons and hence display the buttons?

Comment: here's an example of inheritence that may help http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Objective-C_Inheritance

Comment: Conceptually, that makes sense. However, I'm trying to do this and am struggling with it. TO start with I have my ButtonsViewController (this is what I need all my other classes to inherit from). Now in my TestTableViewController( I"m trying to get these buttons show in this controller too), in the .h file I have thing set up this way: @interface TestTableViewController:UIVewController<UITableViewData,UITableViewDelegate>, TabViewController;
And this doesn't work since I think iOS/objective-c doesn't allow for multiple inheritance

Comment: Okay, the way I have it now is such that in TestTableViewController.h I have 
#import<TabViewController.h>
 @interface TestTableViewController:ButtonsViewController<UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate>
But, this hasn't had the required effect so far in that the buttons are not being reproduced.